# Using toLocaleString() on document.lastModified in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a little script at the bottom of the webpage with the following:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    var d = document.lastModified;
    var n = d.toLocaleString();
    document.write("These documents were last modified on: " + n +"");
</script>
```

However, the date is not modified to my local timezone. I have tried on other peoples' systems (our OS's are definitely English UK). Any idea why?

Thanks,

Harry

Comment: Did you see me answer, can I still help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have php installed check the php ini. Look for timezone and alter it.

**List of Supported Timezones**

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

```
 // php.ini example  

   [Date]
    ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
    ; http://php.net/date.timezone
    date.timezone=Europe/Berlin
```

This script could also work. It gives you your device's time zone setting. https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

I like to add this to my webapps so I can always get the user's timezone.

```
// example implementation 

<script>

$(function() {
  // Get user's timezone
  var tz = jstz.determine();
  timezone = tz.name();

  $('#tz_field').attr('value', timezone);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry man, no PHP allowed - uni assignment. Has to be done with js

Comment: The bottom part is just js

Comment: if you want to use the timezone, simply do new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

Answer (score 0):

`toLocaleString()` converts a Date object to a string, using locale conventions but not to your timezone

> WebKit returns the time string in UTC; Gecko and Internet Explorer return a time in the local timezone 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/lastModified

**Solution:** Convert to timezone:

```js
var d = document.lastModified;
var date = new Date(d);
var n = date.toLocaleString();

// Short
var n = new Date(document.lastModified).toLocaleString();

// Demo:
document.body.innerHTML = n
```